# Splash screen showing progress of GUI being built in Event Dispatch Thread

Tags: java, swing, splash-screen, event-dispatch-thread

According to http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2007/jw-08-swingthreading.html?page=5 all GUI operations should be executed in Event Dispatch Thread.

While I understand the reasons why Swing was designed with single threaded model in mind, I can't figure out how to solve the following problem:

Let's have a method called `buildGui()` which initializes main GUI of the application. Call to `buildGui()` method takes 10 seconds to return.

Let's have another method called `splashScreen()` which shows the `JDialog` with indeterminate `JProgressBar` inside. The purpose of the `JDialog` is obvious: it gives user feedback that application is loading resources, initializing components, etc.

Now, if my program calls:

```
splashScreen();   // build and show splash screen in EDT
buildGui();       // build main GUI in EDT
```

the splash screen is freezed for 10 seconds, because it waits for `buildGui()` to finish.

Do you have any ideas **how to show splash screen which depicts the status of GUI initialization** (`buildGui()`) while following Swing's single threaded model?

Comment: I think you have Swing's model a bit confused. You can create UI components in another thread, but you can't draw them. You can build the GUI in a different thread, but you have to make them visible/draw them in the EDT.

Comment: Also, I'd be curious as to why building the GUI takes that long.

Comment: @Kylar, I'm not sure you are right. Read the http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2007/jw-08-swingthreading.html?page=5 article. Quote: "Once a Swing component has been realized, all code that might affect or depend on the state of that component should be executed in the event-dispatching thread.

**Now throw those instructions out the window**, because around when JSE 1.5 was released all the examples on Sun's site changed."

Comment: @YuRDeD, it's not the point. It simply takes so long, because the device is slow and there are thousands of components to initalize.

Comment: @miso If you are working with a slow device and you are trying to build a UI with thousands of components all at once, I wonder if you shouldn't be rethinking the decisions that went into designing your UI.

Comment: @YuRDeD Please focus on my question. The GUI is great, don't worry. Startup is the only problem.

Comment: 100% ack with @YuRDeD - something is wrong with buildGUI, best to revisit its design: 1000nds of components sound like an awful lot to instantiate at once ... all in one frame/window?

Comment: @miso Just trying to get you to a solution to your problem.  You simply shouldn't block the EDT for ten seconds, and you must do all ui modification on the EDT.  You can't show a progress bar because it would use the EDT as well, which you are blocking.   Unless you rethink your problem more fundamentally, you are stuck.

Comment: *"the device is slow and there are thousands of components to initalize."*  It should be displaying the first dozen or so that the user can see (without scrolling, changing tabs etc.), before constructing the thousands of other components.  Lazy instantiation of GUI components is a useful technique for speeding up a GUI's time to screen.

Comment: Guys, the 10 seconds load time of GUI was just an attempt to illustrate the problem which is: **how to show splash screen for process of Swing GUI initalization?** If I knew you will focus on the way I build the GUI I would never ask this question the way I did. Sorry for that. In fact the GUI I deal with is initalized in few hundreds of milliseconds (500 - 600 ms). However, on some devices it takes 2 to 4 seconds and I would like to show simple splash while it loads. Thats it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Swing tutorial about splash screens](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) which contains sample code doing exactly what you want

Answer (score 3):

Use AWT for splash screens, so they can be loaded prior to loading the Swing package.  The plug-in's own [`SplashScreen`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) is pure AWT.  See also this question re. [use of `SplashScreen` & the EDT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6068069/418556).

While I'm typically saying 'this millennium, use Swing components', it makes a lot of sense to use AWT for a splash.